# PyQt5 TabWidget Implementaion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I am new in python. I make a design form in QtDesigner. Basically the form contains a main window and in that window there is a qtabwidget which contain four tabs. But I did not know how to implement the functionality of all these four tabs in different classes. I want to make the code look neat and clean so trying to divide it in classes of 4 tabs. But I did not know how to do it.

https://codeloop.org/how-to-create-qtabwidget-in-pyqt5/

Above is the link which applies the same functionality which I want. But he create the the whole gui by code in python main file. I want to perform the same functionality if i already created the form in designer.

Comment: Do you mean that you already created the *whole* tab widget (including all its 4 pages) or you created a ui with an *empty* qtabwidget and then 4 *separate* ui for each of those pages?

Comment: Yes I created the whole tab widget including all its its 4 pages in the qt designer.

Comment: Then you cannot: if you want separate classes for each page then you have to create one ui file for the ui with the tabwidget and without *any* page, and a basic widget ("Form") with its own ui for each page. Then each page has to be manually added by code by creating each instance for each page. If you don't know how to properly use designer files in python (and subclass them), read the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (you will nead to create each file using the pyuic tool, then you can import them in your main script).